# Hebrew Ben Chayyim Second Rabbinic Bible is missing Joshua 6:9 to 7:1

Tags: tanach, joshua--book-of, manuscripts

I have a copy of the [Hebrew Ben Chayyim Second Rabbinic Bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikraot_Gedolot#The_Ben_Hayyim_edition) which was scanned and in the book of Joshua it is missing Joshua 6:9 to 7:1.

It is obviously a mistake and not intentional because the chapter numbers carry on as normal. The text should be between pages number 18 and 19.

Is there another edition/copy available online of the Ben Chayyim 2nd Rabbinic Bible where this was printed correctly?

[image: Page 18 of Joshua]

[image: Page 19 of Joshua]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: two pages from book of joshua]

Here are the two pages that your file left out.

Comment: Try this online edition around page 20 https://rosetta.nli.org.il/delivery/DeliveryManagerServlet?dps_pid=IE79468843&_ga=2.172850339.1410575273.1592927422-156867633.1584484337 that link looks bound to die so I'm not including it in the post. If it's dead try something here https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH001268184/NLI